# Keeping empty values after split

Tags: c#, split

I need to split an input value `high/low` that might come in three different forms: `120/50`, `120/`, `/50`, `120`.

I would like to split this into two different variables and check the values I got.

```
var high = input.Split('/').First();
var low = input.Split('/').Last();

if (high.Length > 0) //Do this
if (low.Length > 0) //Do that
```

The problem is that with the two last inputs I get the same value in both `high` and `low`. Which means I can't tell if I got a high value or a low.

I'm starting to suspect I can't use split here?

**EDIT**
It seems as if there are values with no `/` at all. Those values should be interpreted as `high` values.

Comment: Are you saying that for input="120/" you get high="120" and low="120", because you should be getting low=""?

Comment: That's right. It seems as if `.Split()` will discard the value after `/` if it's empty. If you split this into an array it would only contain one element.

Comment: That's weird because I'm pretty sure the default behavior for Split is to include empty elements.  Check my answer for how to explicitly tell it to include empty elements.

Comment: You say "that might come in three different forms". Values ​​come from?

Comment: Why do you think that you cannot use `Split`, what is the real problem? If there's always a `/` in the input string, the array contains  always at least two strings. So i don't see the problem.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into your code to see exactly what the value of input is before you split and what the result for Split is?

Comment: @juharr - Good call. I stepped through about a hundred values and a couple of them didn't have the `/`. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Nullables` and `TryParse` which is safer:

```
string[] parts = input.Split('/');
int? high = null;
int? low = null;
int hightest, lowtest;
if(int.TryParse(parts[0], out hightest))
    high = hightest;
if(int.TryParse(parts[1], out lowtest))
    low = lowtest;
```

Now you can check if they are set with the [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) property, for example:

```
if(high.HasValue)
{
    int val = high.Value;
    // do something with it
}
```

Comment: -1 This does not address the problem that Split is apparently returning an array with only one value.

Comment: @juharr: Actually it's the only approach which addresses the problem(using `int.TryParse`). `"/456"` will be treated different to `"123/"`, the first will set `high` and the second input will set `low`. Side-note: do you really need to downvote competitive answers?

Comment: If the empty values are being removed then parts will have one item and calling parts[1] will result in an Exception.

Comment: @juharr: `int.TryParse` will not throw an exception and if there's an `/` in the string, `string.Split('/')` will always have at least the `Length` 2. OP has only provided  sample data which contains the separator. So again, `/456` will be parsed correctly.

Comment: Int.TryParse doesn't throw and exception if the value you pass is not an int.  You however are trying to pass a value from outside of an array's bounds.

Comment: @juharr: If you'd read my last comment you'd see that it's not possible that the array's length is 1 when there's a `/` in the input string. Btw, how do you know that  OP gets an `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: I don't think he gets the exception.  But if he is getting an array with only one value, which is what his post indicates, then your answer would result in an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  My guess is that the `/` is not present.  And really he isn't even talking about converting to ints anyway.

Comment: @juharr: No, you have misinterpreted the question. He has clearly mentioned that the input contains `/`. He just looked for a way to handle empty values in the array corectly. Everything else is idle speculation.

Comment: Did you even read his edit?

Comment: Yes, the edit is useless since he hasn't mentioned the problem or why he thinks that he cannot use  `Split`. This is the question's core issue: _"The problem is that with the two last inputs I get the same value in both high and low. Which means I can't tell if I got a high value or a low"_. That is covered by my answer.

Comment: If he gets the same value in high and low then Split only returned one value.  Those are the variable names, he'd not talking about comparing the values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20636/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-juharr)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] values = input.Split('/');
if(values[0] != string.Empty)
 //do this
if(values[1] != string.Empty)
 //do that
```

Comment: This does not address the problem of Split returning an array with only one value.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var values = input.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

To make sure it doesn't remove empty entries, although I thought None was the default.

**EDIT**

In the case where the delimiter is missing you can do the following

```
string high;
string low;
var values = input.Split('/');
high = values[0];
if(input.Length == 2)
{
    low = values[1];
}
```

You might also want to check for more than 2 items returned by split to catch any input that has more than 1 `/` in it.

Comment: It's really weird that that this doesn't work. The documentation says exactly what I want but I still get only one value.

Comment: @Niklas, are you absolutely sure there is a `/` in your input string?